PowerShell script to harvest details of Windows Client & Server platforms
I'm a support analyst/help desk technician by trade. Here's a little PowerShell script I've cobbled together over the years to harvest details of Windows client and/or server platforms.
I use this script as part of my diagnostic process to streamline information gathering, minimize redundant communications, and enhance case note documentation.
It saves me a buttload of time by eliminating guesswork about system architecture and reducing unnecessary communications to obtain details I should have had in the first place.
The script extracts, formats, and writes the following data elements into a text file named ‘System Inventory.txt’ saved in the logged-on user’s Downloads folder:

OS Details
OEM Serial Number
GPU specs
Storage Capacity
Optional Windows Features or Server Roles (contingent upon platform)
ISP Details & External IP Addresses (both IPv4 & IPv6)
Antivirus details
PowerShell & .NET Framework versions
Browser URL associations - 'What did you say your default browser was?'
Critical & Error events over the past 24 hours
Updates & Hotfixes

So, how exactly do I use the script? Real basic:

Share the script with the client
Walk them through running the script
Retrieve the results (if remotely assisting) or have the client send the System Inventory.txt file to me via email
Post the client's system inventory as an internal case note in whatever ITSM\CRM platform (SalesForce, ServiceNow, Remedy, etc) my shop is using
Diagnose, reproduce, and fix the client's issue

I'm very interested in knowing the community's thoughts. Any constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated.
# System Inventory Script Overview

# Ownership:

# This script is the property of William John (Bill) Hamill. Unauthorized copying, distribution, or use of this script is prohibited.

# Synopsis:

# Collects detailed system inventory information, including GPU properties, storage capacity, Windows features, Server Roles, network adapters, 
# ISP details, antivirus details, PowerShell & .NET Framework versions, browser URL associations, critical/error events, and updates/hotfixes.
# Designed to be shared as 'System Inventory.txt' and run in PowerShell ISE using the instructions below.
# Functional within PowerShell or VS Code Console when saved as a .ps1 file (e.g., System Inventory.ps1).

# Instructions:

# 1) Download this text file | Open with Notepad.
# 2) Search for Windows PowerShell ISE | Right-click (Run as Administrator).

#    Note: This script *must* be run as an administrator to work!

# 3) PowerShell ISE | View | Show Script Pane
# 4) Notepad | Control + A to select all text, then Control + C to copy it. 
# 5) PowerShell ISE | Script Pane | Control + V to paste the copied text from Notepad.
# 6) PowerShell ISE | File | Run. The results will be displayed on the screen and saved to your Downloads folder as "System Inventory - <ComputerName>.txt".

# Disclaimer:

# This script is provided "as is," without warranty of any kind. Use at your own risk. The author or distributor shall not be held liable 
# for any damage or issues arising from the use of this script.

# Define Error Handling, Line Breaks, Initialize Output File & Progress Bar

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"; $NewLine = "`n"; $SystemInventory = @(); $Global:TaskCount = 0; $Global:TotalTasks = 13

# Check elevation status, halt if not running as admin.

function Confirm-ElevationStatus {    
    if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator))) {
        Clear-Host; Write-Host "This script must be run as an administrator to work!" -ForegroundColor Red; Write-Host
        exit 1
    }
}

# Bypass execution policy for the current PowerShell session only. Security will be restored to its previous state once this session is closed.

function Disable-ExecutionPolicy {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript('Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process')
}

# Hide the script pane in PowerShell ISE by simulating 'Ctrl + R' key press and clear the console screen

function Hide-ScriptPane {
    if ($host.Name -eq 'Windows PowerShell ISE Host') {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^r")
        Clear-Host
    }
}   

# Graphics Card Details

function Get-GpuProperties {
    try {
        $gpuProperties = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController
        $gpuDetails = foreach ($gpu in $gpuProperties) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Device Name'         = $gpu.Name
                'Video RAM'           = [Math]::Round($gpu.AdapterRAM / 1MB, 2)
                'Driver Version'      = $gpu.DriverVersion
                'Install Date & Time' = $gpu.DriverDate
            } 
        }
        return $gpuDetails
    }   
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while retrieving GPU properties: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Storage Capacity

function Get-FreeSpace {
    try {
        Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
            Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
            @{ Name = "Free Space (GB)"; expression = { "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Freespace / 1GB) } },
            @{ Name = "Total Size (GB)"; expression = { "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1GB) } },
            @{ Name = "Free Space %"   ; expression = { "{0:N2}" -f (($_.Freespace / $_.Size) * 100) } }
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred retrieving free space information: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Optional Windows Features\Active Server Roles

function Get-RolesAndFeatures {
    try {
        $CimSysType = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).ProductType

        if ($CimSysType -eq 1) {
            $FeatureLabel = "# Windows Client - Active Optional Features"  
            $RolesAndFeatures = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object State -EQ 'Enabled' | Select-Object FeatureName | Sort-Object FeatureName          
        }
        else { 
            $FeatureLabel = "# Windows Server - Installed Server Roles"
            $RolesAndFeatures = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object InstallState -EQ 'Installed' | Select-Object DisplayName             
        }
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            FeatureLabel     = $FeatureLabel
            RolesAndFeatures = $RolesAndFeatures
        }
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred retrieving roles and features: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# .Net Properties

function Get-DotNetProperties {

    # Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine

    try {
        # .NET Framework Lookup Table
        $Lookup = @{
            378389 = '4.5'
            378675 = '4.5.1'
            378758 = '4.5.1'
            379893 = '4.5.2'
            393295 = '4.6'
            393297 = '4.6'
            394254 = '4.6.1'
            394271 = '4.6.1'
            394802 = '4.6.2'
            394806 = '4.6.2'
            460798 = '4.7'
            460805 = '4.7'
            461308 = '4.7.1'
            461310 = '4.7.1'
            461808 = '4.7.2'
            461814 = '4.7.2'
            528040 = '4.8'
            528049 = '4.8'
            533320 = '4.8.1'
        }
    
        # Retrieve .NET Framework Versions
        $netFrameworkVersions = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
            Get-ItemProperty -Name Version, Release -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq "Full" } |
                    Select-Object @{ Name = "Client" ; Expression = { $_.PSChildName } },
                                  @{ Name = "Version"; Expression = { $Lookup[$_.Release] } }, 
                                  Release
    
        # Retrieve .NET Core Versions
        $dotNetCoreVersions = & "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --list-runtimes |
            ForEach-Object {
                $parts = $_ -split '\s+'
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'Client'  = $parts[0]
                    'Version' = $parts[1]
                    'Path'    = $parts[2]
                }
            }
    
        # Combine Results
        $combinedResults = @(); $combinedResults += $netFrameworkVersions; $combinedResults += $dotNetCoreVersions
            
        if ($combinedResults) { return $combinedResults } else { Write-Output "No .NET versions found on this machine." }
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while enumerating .NET properties: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# ISP Details & External IP Addresses

function Get-ISPDetails {
    try {
        $IPv4 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://ipinfo.io/'
        $IPv6 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://ident.me/'
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            IPv4 = $IPv4
            IPv6 = $IPv6
        }
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while retrieving ISP details: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Antivirus Details

function Get-AntiVirus {

    # Source:  https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/5187/get-antivirus-product-status-with-powershell/
    
    try {
        $antivirus = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -ClassName "AntiVirusProduct"
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while retrieving antivirus information: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        return
    }

    # Decode hexadecimal productState value to derive Enabled & UpToDate values (True or False)
    
    Function ConvertTo-Hex {
        Param([int]$Number)
        try {
            return '0x{0:x}' -f $Number
        }
        catch {
            throw "Failed to convert number to hexadecimal: $($_.Exception.Message)"
            return $null
        }
    }
    $AntiVirusDetails = $antivirus | ForEach-Object {
        try {
            $hx = ConvertTo-Hex $_.ProductState
            if ($hx -and $hx.Length -ge 5) {
                $mid = $hx.Substring(3, 2)
                $Enabled = if ($mid -match "00|01") { $False } else { $True }

                $end = $hx.Substring(5)
                $UpToDate = if ($end -eq "00") { $True } else { $False }
            }
            else {
                $Enabled = $False
                $UpToDate = $False
            }

    # Collect and format results

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Display Name"  = $_.displayName
                "Install Path"  = $_.pathToSignedReportingExe
                "Enabled"       = $Enabled
                "Updated"       = $UpToDate
                "Latest Scan"   = Get-Date $_.timestamp -Format "dddd, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
                "Computer"      = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            }
        }
        catch {
            throw "Failed to process antivirus product: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
    $AntiVirusDetails
}

# Browser URL Associations

function Get-BrowserURL {
    try {
        $AppHash = @{}
        $RegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations"
        Get-ChildItem "$RegPath\*\UserChoice\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            ForEach-Object {
                $AppHash.Add((Get-Item $_.PSParentPath).PSChildName, $_.GetValue('progId'))
            }
        if ( $AppHash.Count -gt 0 ) { $AppHash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value, Name } 
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while retrieving browser URL associations: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Event Log Activity

function Get-CriticalErrorEvents {
    try {
        $startTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
        
        $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
            LogName   = 'System', 'Application'
            Level     = 1, 2  
            StartTime = $startTime
        }         
        $events | Select-Object LevelDisplayName, Id, TimeCreated, ProviderName, Message | Sort-Object LevelDisplayName, ID
    }
    catch {
        if ($_.Exception.Message -match "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria") {
            Write-Output $NewLine
            Write-Output "No Critical or Error events raised over the past 24 hours."
            Write-Output $NewLine
        }
        else {
            throw "An error occurred while retrieving the event logs: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}

# Updates & Hotfixes 
  
function Get-WindowsUpdateHistory {
    try {
        $Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
        $Search  = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
        $Count   = $Search.GetTotalHistoryCount()
        $Patch   = $Search.QueryHistory(0, $Count)
        $Updates = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        
        foreach ($Update in $Patch) {
            if ($Update.Operation -eq 1 -and $Update.ResultCode -eq 2 -and $Update.Title -notlike '*KB2267602*') {
               
                # Daily virus definition updates filtered for brevity: KB2267602 Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus

                $Updates.Add([PSCustomObject]@{            
                        'KB Number'   = [regex]::match($Update.Title, 'KB(\d+)').Value
                        'Installed'   = $Update.Date
                        'Title'       = $Update.Title
                        'Description' = $Update.Description
                    }) | Out-Null
            } 
        } 
        $Updates 
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while retrieving Windows update history: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Progress Bar Helper Function

function Update-Progress {
    param (
        [string]$Activity, 
        [string]$Status
    )
    try {
        $global:TaskCount++
        Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -Status $Status -PercentComplete (($global:TaskCount / $global:TotalTasks) * 100)          
    }
    catch {
        throw "An error occurred while updating progress: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Verify elevation, configure environment

Confirm-ElevationStatus; Disable-ExecutionPolicy; Hide-ScriptPane

# Current Date

$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format F 
$SystemInventory = "# Current Date", $NewLine, $TimeStamp, $NewLine | Out-String 

# Detailed System Information

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Detailed Operating System Information" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$OS = systeminfo.exe
$SystemInventory += "# Operating System", $OS, $NewLine | Out-String 

# OEM Identifier

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "OEM Identifier\Serial Number\Service Tag" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$OemUniqueId = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Bios | Select-Object SerialNumber
$SystemInventory += "# OEM Identifier", $OemUniqueId | Out-String 

# Graphics Card Details

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Graphics Card Details" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$GraphicCards = Get-GpuProperties | Sort-Object 'Video Ram' -Descending
$SystemInventory += "# Graphic Cards", $GraphicCards | Out-String

# Storage Capacity

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Storage Capacity" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$Storage = Get-FreeSpace | Format-Table -AutoSize
$SystemInventory += "# Storage Capacity", $Storage | Out-String

# Server Roles\Optional Windows Features

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Server Roles\Optional Windows Features" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$Results = Get-RolesAndFeatures
$SystemInventory += $Results.FeatureLabel, $Results.RolesAndFeatures | Out-String

# Network Adapters & Mac Addresses 

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Network Adapters & Mac Addresses" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$NetAdapters = Get-NetAdapter | Format-Table -AutoSize
$SystemInventory += "# Network Adapters & Mac Addresses", $NetAdapters | Out-String

# ISP Details & External IP Addresses

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "ISP Details & External IP Addresses" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$ISPDetails = Get-ISPDetails
$SystemInventory += "# ISP Details & External IP Addresses", $ISPDetails.IPv4, $ISPDetails.IPv6 | Out-String

# Security Posture - Antivirus\Antimalware Details

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Security Posture - Antivirus\Antimalware Details" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$AntiVirus = Get-AntiVirus
$SystemInventory += "# Antivirus Details", $AntiVirus | Out-String

# PowerShell 

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "PowerShell Details" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$PoSh = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion 
$SystemInventory += "# PowerShell", $PoSh | Out-String

# .Net Properties

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status ".NET Properties" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$NetFrmWrk = Get-DotNetProperties
$SystemInventory += "# .Net Framework", $NetFrmWrk | Out-String

# Browswer URL Associations

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Browswer URL Associations" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$BrowserURLs = Get-BrowserURL 
$SystemInventory += "# Browser URL Associations", $BrowserURLs | Out-String

# Event Log Activity

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Event Log Activity" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)
$EventLogActivty = Get-CriticalErrorEvents | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
$SystemInventory += "# Event Log Activity", $EventLogActivty | Out-String

# Updates & Hotfixes 

Update-Progress -Activity "Gathering system inventory" -Status "Updates & Hotfixes" -PercentComplete (($TaskCount / $TotalTasks) * 100)  
$UpdateHistory = Get-WindowsUpdateHistory | Select-Object "KB Number", Installed, Title | Sort-Object Installed -Descending 
$SystemInventory += "# Updates & Hotfixes", $UpdateHistory | Out-String

# Save & Display Results

Clear-Host
$FileName = Join-Path $Env:USERPROFILE "Downloads\System Inventory - $($Env:COMPUTERNAME).txt"
$SystemInventory | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding ascii
Get-Content -Path $FileName
Write-Host "Hard copy saved as" $FileName; Write-Host

